# Simulate serial printer on pc

Tags: c#, serial-port

I have an old lab device which prints it's result to a serial printer. I need to replace the serial printer with a computer. I have connected the device's 9 pin serial port to the computer's serial port, and started hyperterminal with the connection setting as described in the manual. The settings are as follows:

- Printer interface
- V.24 ( RS 232 C )
- 9600 baud
- 1 start bit
- 7 data bits
- 1 parity bit
- 1 stop bit
- output only, no control lines.

For some reason hyperterminal does not display any result from the unit. Is there something I am missing? Do I require a special serial cable? If I can get the result in Hyperterminal, I would be able to develop my C# program.

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: This is a hardware issue, not a programming issue. Stackoverflow is the wrong place for this question.

Comment: I have previously communicated with other serial devices with c#. For some reason I cannot read the output from the device which is meant for a serial printer. Thus I believe it is either a communication port setup, physical cable setup, or some communication which must first be send to the device to let it know it can transmit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried a null modem cable? It's a cable that has RX/TX cross connected. A  pinout should be published somewhere.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have purchased a serial data cable from our local pc store. Would that be a null modem cable, or must I ask specific for it?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're after is a [Null Modem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_modem_cable#Cables_and_adapters) cable.  You may have trouble finding one any more though.

Comment: Thank you for the link; I will use the information to ask the pc shop to make up one for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to simulate a serial device, you could try [com0com](http://com0com.sourceforge.net/) to set up a virtual serial port.

Comment: Thanks you for your help. I have downloaded it, and will test it today.